# Android: How does dp work, and can I test it?

Tags: android

I was wondering, I now have an app that makes a grid of 16x16 buttons which are all 30dp wide. That makes a total of 480dp. In the emulator it runs fine (which runs at WVGA). Can I change the screen size of the emulator in any way to test if my app runs fine on lower and higher screen resolutions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define different AVDs using the [AVD manager](http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/devices/index.html). When you launch the AVD, you can specify a virtual-to-screen scaling, which will also affect the density that the emulator will use.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, of course. You can do that in the AVD manager. Start your virtual device from AVD and a little dialog will pop-up asking you if you would like to set a custom size for the device. Alternatively you can create additional avd entries.